# error trying to creating webhook smartsheet

Tags: webhooks, smartsheet-api

Only URLs with a protocol of `'https'` are supported for attribute `'callbackUrl'`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means exactly what it says: the value that you specify for the `callbackUrl` property in the [Create Webhook](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#create-webhook) request must begin with `https:`. If the value you specify for the `callbackUrl` property begins with `http:` then you'll receive this error message in response. This restriction is in place for security reasons -- i.e., Smartsheet will only send webhook notifications to secure endpoints.

Comment: thanks Kim, i appreciate your response ! i had to correct the sintaxis , and its working right now!

Comment: Happy I could help!